# How to display modification time of a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'd like a method to find and print the modified time of a file, for use within a bash script.

I have come up with:

```
ls -l $filename | cut -d ' ' -f '6-8'
```

Which outputs:

```
Jul 26 15:05
```

Though I'd like to avoid parsing `ls`, also it'd be useful to have the year in there.

Ideally I'd like to see an output similar to the default output of the `date` command.

```
Tue Jul 26 15:20:59 BST 2016
```

What other useful methods are available?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Don't use `ls`, this is a job for `stat`:

```
stat -c '%y' filename
```

`-c` lets us to get specific output, here `%y` will get us the last modified time of the file in human readable format. To get time in seconds since Epoch use `%Y`:

```
stat -c '%Y' filename
```

If you want the file name too, use `%n`:

```
stat -c '%y : %n' filename
stat -c '%Y : %n' filename
```

Set the format specifiers to suit your need. Check `man stat`.

**Example:**

```
% stat -c '%y' foobar.txt
2016-07-26 12:15:16.897284828 +0600

% stat -c '%Y' foobar.txt
1469513716

% stat -c '%y : %n' foobar.txt
2016-07-26 12:15:16.897284828 +0600 : foobar.txt    

% stat -c '%Y : %n' foobar.txt
1469513716 : foobar.txt
```

---

If you want the output like `Tue Jul 26 15:20:59 BST 2016`, use the Epoch time as input to `date`:

```
% date -d "@$(stat -c '%Y' a.out)" '+%a %b %d %T %Z %Y'
Tue Jul 26 12:15:21 BDT 2016

% date -d "@$(stat -c '%Y' a.out)" '+%c'               
Tue 26 Jul 2016 12:15:21 PM BDT

% date -d "@$(stat -c '%Y' a.out)"
Tue Jul 26 12:15:21 BDT 2016
```

Check `date`'s format specifiers to meet your need. See `man date` too.

Comment: Further to this answer, bear in mind that `ls` is inconsistently implemented across systems, and so should _never_ be used for any sort of automation. Instead, use commands such as `stat` and `find` when writing scripts.

Comment: excellent. I had not known about this little treasure. So many of them in the *nix/linux environment yet to be discovered.

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
ls -l $filename | cut -d ' ' -f '6-8'
```

but if the date is less than 10 it misses the time. This because of the extra space before the date if less than 10. Try this:

```
filename="test.txt"
ls -l $filename | awk -F ' ' '{print $6" "$7" "$8}'
```

The awk command prints the fields separated by all spaces (-F ' '). Hope it works. I know this doesn't answer the original question but just a clarification on the ls command for just date and time. When you Google "ubuntu get date and time of file" it lists this question at the top, which is what I was looking for, since I don't need the year also. For year, date and time, you could try one of the commands below. %m prints month number. %b prints month abbreviation:
Drop the %H:%M if you don't need the hour and minute. %-d doesn't print leading zero for the day of the month.

```
date -r $filename +"%Y %m %-d %H:%M"
date -r $filename +"%y %m %-d %H:%M"
date -r $filename +"%Y %b %-d %H:%M"
date -r $filename +"%y %b %-d %H:%M"
```